# Solving the trigonometric equation $2\sin(t)-1-\sin^2(t) = 0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Find all solutions of $2\sin t-1-\sin^2 t = 0$ in $[0,2\pi]$.

Attempt: 
\begin{align}
1-2\sin t& =-\sin^2 t\\
\cos 2t& =-\sin^2 t\\
\cos^2t-\sin^2t & =-\sin^2t\\
\cos^2t & = 0. 
\end{align}
Am I correct up to this point? If I have done everything right, I do not know where to go from here. I know how to solve $\cos t=0$ but $\cos^2$ is confusing me. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.  I'm sure you'll get much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: No, $\cos 2t = 1-2\sin^2 t$.

Comment: You made a mistake. $cos(2t)$ equals $1-2sin^2t$ and not $1-2sint$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $$\sin(t)=z$$ then we get
$$2z-1-z^2=0$$ which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{array}{llll}
2sin(t)-1-sin^2(t)=0\implies 0=\stackrel{\textit{notice, is just }ax^2+bx+c}{sin^2(t)-2sin(t)+1}
\\ \quad \\
0=[sin(t)-1][sin(t)-1]\implies 1=sin(t)
\\ \quad \\
sin^{-1}(1)=sin^{-1}[sin(t)]\implies sin^{-1}(1)=t\implies {\color{blue}{ \cfrac{\pi }{2}=t }}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  If you type \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, \cot x when you are in math mode, you will obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, and $\cot x$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It’s quite simple to solve. Although not necessary, simply substitute $\sin (t)$ with $t$ or any other variable, which leads to a normal quadratic equation.
$2\sin (t)-1-\sin^2 (t)$ = $0$
$2t-1-t^2$ = $0$
$-t^2+2t-1$ = $0$ $\Rightarrow$ $t^2-2t+1$ = $0$ $\Rightarrow$ $(t-1)^2$ = $0$ $\Rightarrow$ $t-1$ = $0$ $\Rightarrow$ $t$ = $1$
Now, simply plug in $\sin (t)$ = $t$.
$\sin (t)$ = $1$ $\Rightarrow$ $t$ = $\sin^-1 (1)$ = $\frac{\pi}{2}$
However, the question asks for a complete set of solutions, rather than those for $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$, so our complete answer is $t$ = $\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n$ for all integer values of $n$.
(You made a mistake when attempting to simplify $1-2\sin (t)$ = $-\sin^2 (t)$. $\cos (2t)$ = $1-2\sin^2 (t)$, NOT $1-2\sin (t)$.)

Answer (score 0):

Let sin t = p
So, the equation become 2t - 1 - t^2 =0
Ans then factorized it.so that I get thevalue of t.
And then you can come back to the sin t=p
And find t fter that